# scope problems - exiting out of loop

Tags: javascript, scope

I have the following code in javascript:

```
var continueloop = true;

while (continueloop === true) {
    main()
}
```

and

```
function main() {
    //do some stuff here
    continueloop = false;
}
```

setting continueloop's value to false inside the main function does not cause the while loop to stop. I suspect that it might have to do with javascript's function scoping, but I could be mistaken could someone explain to me what I have to change in order to get the desired effect with the continueloop variable accessible to the scope of the main() function?

thanks!

Comment: Is this code inside a function, or are both `main` and `continueloop` global?  Can you show us where these functions/variables are declared.  Because it works fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/Dc26x/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why don't you just return if it should continue? It's cleaner and you won't run into any scope problems either.

```
var continueloop = true;

while (continueloop === true) {
    continueloop = main();
}

function main() {
    //do some stuff here
    return false;
}

// or
while(main());
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to recursively call main() if the continueloop condition is met.
Depending on your application, this might allow you to keep continueloop local to main().

```
function main() {
    var continueloop = false;
    if (continueloop == true) {
        main();
    }
}

main();
```